# Layer on top of my object looks wierd after extruding certain vertices

Tags: modeling, vertices, extrude

[image: Picture in edit mode.][image: I am following a tutorial on youtube, where I am currently adding icing on top of a donut. This is what the icing normally looks like.]

[image: I selected two vertices an extruded them and after that, I noticed that there were vertices on my donut which weren't there before, so after I deleted those vertices which weren't part of where I wanted them to be, the icing started looking weird as if it is building in on itself. The offset in the solidify is set to '1' and I have set the Levels Viewpoint in subdivision to '2']
[image: This is another example of such a thing occurring. It could be that I accidently selected the vertices opposite to my facing side and then accidently moved them while extruding and then deleted them.]
It could be that I accidently selected the vertices opposite to my facing side and then accidently moved them while extruding and then deleted them.

Comment: can u add a picture in edit mode?

Comment: I have edited the post and added the picture. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5wRm.png)
I apologize for late reply.

Comment: @ blenderuser_-29185 select the outermost edge by pressing down alt and scale it.

Comment: scaling is making it look wierder, am I doing somtthing wrong scaling or could it be that there is another solution?

Comment: redo that icing or just upload your blend file i'll fix it for u.

Comment: I think I will just redo it, thank you for your help!